# If my breakers in my wall aren't covered by a panel door or anything, can they screw a thin metallic sheet to the front of my breaker?

Tags: circuit-breaker

Is it a violation of a code to place a thin metallic sheet over my breaker box?? It looks very trifling and unsafe!!

Comment: That sounds very strange. The panel should not need a screwdriver to gain access - that would be quite a problem in an emergency situation.

Comment: Please edit to add a picture.

Comment: We need to see a photograph of what you're looking at there.  I'm unclear if the panel is missing its deadfront (the part that keeps curious fingers out of the hot power rails and lugs), had a thin metal sheet installed as a replacement deadfront, or is intact but has been covered over by building materials.

Comment: Can you post photos of the panel in question please? We can't tell from your description whether you're referring to the panel's *deadfront* (something very important to have for safety's sake as it keeps pokey bits away from electrically live/"hot" bits) or to the *door* that covers the breaker handles on most panels (which is itself merely a cosmetic nicety -- some small panels don't have doors, just a deadfront that has slots in it for the breaker faces)

Comment: Or if posting photos doesn't work for you ,can you tell us if all you can see is sheet metal and breaker handles, or if you can see the wiring connected to the breakers as well?

Comment: Or is all you can see a sheet of metal screwed down and you don't see any breakers at all?